# Why loss function always return zero after first epoch?

Tags: python, pytorch, conv-neural-network

Why the loss function is always printing zero after the first epoch?

I suspect it's because of `loss = loss_fn(outputs, torch.max(labels, 1)[1])`.

But if I use `loss = loss_fn(outputs, labels)`, I will get the error

```
RuntimeError: 0D or 1D target tensor expected, multi-target not supported
```

.

```
nepochs = 5

losses = np.zeros(nepochs)

loss_fn = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

optimizer = optim.Adam(modell.parameters(), lr = 0.001)

for epoch in range(nepochs):

    running_loss = 0.0
    n = 0
    
    for data in train_loader:
        
        #single batch
        if(n == 1):
            break;
            
        inputs, labels = data
        
        optimizer.zero_grad()

        outputs = modell(inputs)
        
        #loss = loss_fn(outputs, labels)
        loss = loss_fn(outputs, torch.max(labels, 1)[1])
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
    
        running_loss += loss.item()
        n += 1
       
    losses[epoch] = running_loss / n
    print(f"epoch: {epoch+1} loss: {losses[epoch] : .3f}")
```

The model is:

```
def __init__(self, labels=10):
    super(Classifier, self).__init__()
    self.fc = nn.Linear(3 * 64 * 64, labels)
    
def forward(self, x):
    out = x.reshape(x.size(0), -1) 
    out = self.fc (out)
    return out
```

Any idea?

The labels are a 64 elements tensor like this:

```
tensor([[7],[1],[ 2],[3],[ 2],[9],[9],[8],[9],[8],[ 1],[7],[9],[2],[ 5],[1],[3],[3],[8],[3],[7],[1],[7],[9],[8],[ 8],[3],[7],[ 5],[ 1],[7],[3],[2],[1],[ 3],[3],[2],[0],[3],[4],[0],[7],[1],[ 8],[4],[1],[ 5],[ 3],[4],[3],[ 4],[8],[4],[1],[ 9],[7],[3],[ 2],[ 6],[4],[ 8],[3],[ 7],[3]])
```

Comment: Depends on what `labels` contains. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @GoodDeeds, labels is a tensor with 64 elements with the ID of each label. I've added a sample in the question.

Comment: I think the loss should be  `loss = loss_fn(outputs, torch.max(labels, 1)[0])`

Comment: That worked @yakhyo! Thanks!

Comment: @jimmy, i updated the answer. I think I did small mistake in my comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually loss calculation is `loss = loss_fn(outputs, labels)` and here `outputs` is as following:

```
_ , outputs = torch.max(model(input), 1)
or
outputs = torch.max(predictions, 1)[0]
```

Common practice is modifying `outputs` instead of `labels`:

> `torch.max()` returns a namedtuple `(values, indices)` where values is
> the maximum value of each row of the `input` tensor in the given
> dimension `dim`. And `indices` is the index location of each maximum value found (`argmax`).

In your code snippet the `labels` is not indices of the labels, so when you calculate the loss, the function should look like this:

```
loss = loss_fn(torch.max(outputs, 1)[0], labels)
```

Comment: That will return the error: `IndexError: Dimension out of range (expected to be in range of [-1, 0], but got 1)`. Just remembering that the `labels` are the id's of each label.

Comment: Did you mean `loss = loss_fn(outputs, torch.max(labels, 1)[1])` ?

Comment: nope, it should be `loss = loss_fn(torch.max(outputs, 1)[0], labels)`, edited answer again)